# Lookup column adding new columns from source list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column

This is on SharePoint Online. I have two lists, A and B. List B contains a column which is a lookup column from List A and also pulls in some additional columns.

I've now added a new column in List A, but it seems impossible to add that column to what appears in List B.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What data type are the new columns?

Comment: what's the relation between the new column in list A and the list B>!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Single line of text, Number and Date and Time column type can be selected for additional columns (secondary columns).

Check the article: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns: creating lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: Thanks, that was it, it was choice not single line of test.